# File layout for multiple executables in a library crate

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to create a rust package with two binary crates and a library which contains the shared code. I know how do do this for a simple program by putting the source files for the binaries in a `src/bin/` subdirectory (e.g. `src/bin/firstbin.rs` and `src/bin/secondbin.rs`) and the library code either in `src/` or in `src/lib/`.

However, if the binaries have a substantial amount of non-shared code which does not belong in the library, and I want to split their source into multiple files, I'm not sure of how to lay out the source files. I'm thinking something along the lines of having `src/bin/firstbin/` for the files which belong only to the first binary, and `src/bin/secondbin/` for the second binary. However, I'm not sure how to reference these files from `firstbin.rs` and `secondbin.rs`.

So is this the right approach and if so how do I reference the files? If not, what's the best layout?

Comment: Is only one package mandatory? I would use different crates if I were you.

Comment: I'm new to rust so still figuring out the best approach. Splitting this into multiple packages seems overkill though.The code is closely related and I'd expect it to be kept together. For example, I'd expect it all to be in a single git repository. There is obviously some expectation of multiple binaries in one package - hence the support for multiple source files in the src/bin directory - but if they are only single files that seems very limiting unless you have very large files. I prefer to keep source files to no more than 100 to 200 lines if possible.

Comment: You can have several crates (packages) in one project: https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L79 IMO, the mix of a library and a binary in one crate is useful when the only function of your binary is to call your library, when all the work is done. For a more complex project, it is better to split that in different crates.

Comment: Wow! That's a bit over my head - my Cargo.toml files are all less than 10 lines long! By splitting into different crates, do you mean different packages?

Comment: If you go for several crates, check out workspaces: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section

Comment: @Bob A package in Rust is named a "crate".

Comment: @French I don't think that's quite right. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates-for-making-libraries-and-executables.html says "A package has a Cargo.toml that describes how to build one or more crates. At most one crate in a package can be a library."

Comment: @Bob Oh, ok, thanks! TIL.

Comment: Please note: Shepmaster has marked this as a duplicate, but the questions referenced as duplicates do not (quite) address the question I was asking. However, starblue's answer below does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your `fn main()` into  `src/bin/firstbin/main.rs` and add more files for submodules in the same directory. This is documented in [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-project-layout) of the Cargo manual (in the text, the gray box is wrong).

Comment: Can I ask why you edited the title of my question? I think it's not quite right as I was specifically asking about three crates in one package: a library crate and two binary crates. The executables are not in the library crate - they are crates within the package.

Comment: Don't be too nitpicky about crate vs package, most people will always use crate. I'll have to check when that disctinction was added in the manual, it feels recent to me (but I might be wrong).